# javascript reload combined with scroll

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript function; it works fine when I use the reload alone and works fine when I use the scroll alone; but it will not scroll when I combine the two together; I tried to change the sequence, but did not help;

```
function myFunction() {
    window.open("http://www.example.com");
    location.reload(true);
    window.scrollBy(0,1000);
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: So you want to reload the page and then scroll by 1000px?

Comment: yes exactly I want both

Comment: How to do this in dom storage?

Comment: You'll need to store the scroll state in dom storage.

Comment: cookies, local storage, session storage or hastags - 4 options you have...probably more

Comment: do you mean my javascript is not correct??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set hash to `somehash` and then reload the page. After that, in your body `onload`, check the hash and if hash is `somehash`, scroll the page.

```
function myFunction() {
    window.open("http://www.example.com");
    location.hash = 'somehash';
    location.reload(true);
}
```

Add the following function to your page `onload` event handler.

```
function scrollOnload() {
    if (location.hash == 'somehash') {
        window.scrollBy(0,1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good option, though I would go with something more meaningful than "somehash". :)

Comment: Thanks nisargjhaveri; I will try it, and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make browser do something after reload, you need to keep the flag somewhere. Here is an example using `sessionStorage`:

```
function myFunction() {
    window.open("http://www.example.com");
    sessionStorage.setItem('scroll', true);
    location.reload(true);
}

document.body.addEventListener('load', function () {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('scroll')) {
        window.scrollBy(0, 1000);
        sessionStorage.removeItem('scroll');
    }
});
```